# Managing multiple threads and general code flow

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop

There's a lot of code here so let me explain quickly what it is *supposed* to do.

### Expected flow:

1. `GetScenarios();` opens a SQL connection and starts a `while` loop to loop through a `Scenarios` database.
2. When the first item in the database is selected, run `TestScenarios()` on it.
3. `TestScenarios()` reads some of the item's XML values, one of which is `Url`, and then opens up the `Url` in a `WebBrowser` control.
4. When that webpage is open, some Javascript is injected and invoked in order to `click` (test) an element on the page.
5. The if statement `TestUrl.Equals(expected)` should return `true`.

---

I'm having trouble when invoking a `new Action` to inject some javascript.

The javascript function that tests if `TestUrl.Equals(expected)` **should** return `true`, but for some odd reason, when I step through my program, **it seems to run everything twice**... with the `if` statement first coming out as `false` and then as `true`.

I think this is a threading/code flow issue but I'm not sure where.  I was thinking to put all the code that runs after the `Navigate()` function **inside of** the `WebBrowserDocumentCompleted` function, but I can't figure out how to pass any of my variables inside that function, so I'm not sure how that'd work.

```
    public void GetScenarios()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Scenarios WHERE IsEnabled='1'", conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            /* Perform a test on the selected scenario
                             * (can do different types of tests)                              
                             * */
                            TestScenarios(reader, cmd, signal, Url, HasSucceeded);
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits for WebBrowser to complete loading the page
    /// </summary>
    private void WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs Url)
    {
        ((AutoResetEvent)((WebBrowser)sender).Tag).Set();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Goes to specified Url
    /// Performs a test on the selected scenario
    /// </summary>
    public int TestScenarios(SqlDataReader reader, SqlCommand cmd, AutoResetEvent signal, string Url, int HasSucceeded)
    {
        // Read XML
        string testType = "";
        string testElement = "";
        string expected = "";

        SqlXml sqlXml = reader.GetSqlXml(1);
        using (var xmlreader = sqlXml.CreateReader())
        {
            // Read XML values
        }

        // Navigate to Url
        Action action = () =>
        {
            webBrowser2.Tag = signal;
            webBrowser2.Navigate(Url);
            webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
            webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
        };
        webBrowser2.Invoke(action);
        signal.WaitOne();


        // If/else to determine type of test and run test
        if (testType == "Click")
        {
            webBrowser2.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                HtmlElement head = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                HtmlElement testScript = webBrowser2.Document.CreateElement("script");
                IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)testScript.DomElement;
                element.text = "function TestClick() { $('" + testElement + "')[0].click(); }";
                head.AppendChild(testScript);
                webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("TestClick");

                string TestUrl = webBrowser2.Url.AbsoluteUri;
                if (TestUrl.Equals(expected))
                {
                    HasSucceeded = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // No test
                }
            }));
        }
        return HasSucceeded;
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that the return HasSucceeded has already been done and after that the action has been invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is better to use Task or Task TResult instead of Thread. You can Execute the Action inside a Task and wait till completion and return the result

```
Func<bool> action = () =>
        {
            HtmlElement head = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement testScript = webBrowser2.Document.CreateElement("script");
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement) testScript.DomElement;
            element.text = "function TestClick() { $('" + testElement + "')[0].click(); }";
            head.AppendChild(testScript);
            webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("TestClick");

            string TestUrl = webBrowser2.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            if (TestUrl.Equals(expected)) {
                HasSucceeded = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // No test
            }

            return HasSucceeded;
        };

        Task<bool> task = new Task<bool>(action);
        task.Start();
        task.Wait();
        return task.Result;
```